# Python: run script in background and do input/output

Tags: python, scripting, memcached

I need to make script that will be run in background, script will have always opened connection to memcached server and wating to get parametars from other program, when recive parametar script will do some work and output some information back to that first program.
My bigest problem is how to make that script run in background and to wait for parametar?

Comment: How is it getting parameters from the other program? From a socket?

Comment: Soory i forgot to say, i pass parametars with simple command line " ./app.py --information " and i expect around 1000-2000 parametars (sended to that script) in one second...

Comment: How can you pass parameters on the command line when the script is already running? That doesn't make any sense. Of course you can write a driver script (which stays running in the background) and a control script, like, e.g., `httpd` and `apachectl`, and you can even merge them both into the same script (so it acts as the driver with one set of params, controls an existing driver otherwise), but that doesn't sound like what you're suggesting.

Comment: Also, when you say "I expect around 1000-2000 parameters", do you mean 2000 command line args?

Comment: "How can you pass parameters on the command line when the script is already running?" Thats why I post question here :) Somehow i need to make script who will recieve some information and pass back some other information. And i was mean 1000-2000 hits/request per seconds. Can you give me some better idea? Socket is not good in my position.

Comment: I don't understand what you're attempting to do, so I don't know how to help you. And are you talking 1000-2000 people running your control script locally every second? Also, what's wrong with sockets for your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how you're getting parameters from the other program, or how you're waiting, it's hard to give a specific answer.

But let's assume, for the sake of exposition, that it's listening for TCP connections to port 6789, and the other program just connects to that socket and sends a fixed number of parameters, separated by newlines.

The simplest way to do this is to just block:

```
memcache_connection = # however you set this up
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 6789))
sock.listen(5)
while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    with contextlib.closing(conn) as client:
        with client.makefile() as f:
            param1, param2, param3 = f
        result = do_memcache_stuff(memcache_connection, param1, param2, param3)
        client.sendall(result)
```

Obviously there's no error-handling here, and no way to quit other than ^C, but that stuff is easy to add.

More seriously, it can only handle one command at a time. If that's a problem, you have the usual two choices: threading, or an event loop. Threading is generally simpler if you don't need to share information between two client connections and you don't need to handle more than a few dozen at a time. All you have to do is wrap up the handler in a function, then spawn it. So:

```
def handle_client(conn):
    with contextlib.closing(conn) as client:
        with client.makefile() as f:
            param1, param2, param3 = f
        result = do_memcache_stuff(memcache_connection, param1, param2, param3)
        client.sendall(result)

memcache_connection = # however you set this up
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 6789))
sock.listen(5)
while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    t = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting to do what's called multi threading, read up on it in the python documentation or try it out yourself:

```
import threading
```